# Add a category to posts, that DO NOT contain two specific keywords?

Tags: posts, categories, query

i'm a little bit underwhelmed. I use mostly plugins for everything but i think there is none that does that job. I'm looking to add a category (ID 18663) to posts that **do not** contain two specific words: PEG and PPG. I want to do that so that readers can search specific for microplastics and polymerfree products, which i already have a great plugin for (WP Grid Builder). Any help would be awesome!